# Is compiler smart enough to optimize this?

Tags: c

In the following lines:

```
typedef struct foo {.....} foo_t;
foo_t array[1000];
foo_t* ptr = &array[50];
```

Will the the last line be equivalent to

```
 foo_t* ptr = array + 50
```

Because, supposing `foo_t` is large, it would be expensive to convert `array[50]` to an instance of `foo_t`, and then take the address.

Comment: Errr... I don't think *any* compiler would make this operation "expensive". All that's being handled here are pointers in the first place, i.e. no type conversion happening. `array[50]` *is* an instance of `foo_t`, and taking its address is dirt cheap...

Comment: What's the difference? Still has to multiply by the `struct` size anyway. I believe some processors/assemblers have built-in indexing to access arrays of element size `2` or `4` etc, but any array element size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a reasonable compiler, the compiler should generate the equivalent of:

```
ptr = (char*)array + 50 * sizeof(foo_t);
```

for both those cases, yes. (the cast to `char*` is there only to exaplain that the `sizeof(foo_t)` is required to be multiplied into the statement.

There is really no other way to find the value of the `&array[50]` anyway.

Note that the key point of `50 * sizeof(foo_t)` is that we need to MULTIPLY the index to make a byte address value, before adding to `array`'s base address. For a typical case, the address of `array` is constant and the offset is constant [the `sizeof(foo_t)` is by nature constant, or you can't declare an array of the variable anyway], the compiler will of course optimise the whole of `array + 50 * sizeof(foo_t)` such that it is just a constant in the code (once it's linked and relocated for the data address).

If `50` is replaced by `x`, a value known only at runtime, there will be a multiplication before the add [the multiplication canbe optimised into a faster operation if the multiplicand is simple enough, e.g. `x * 9` = `x * 8 + x` as one instruction, because there is support to multiply by 1, 2, 4, 8 and 16 - at least in some processors, and even RISC processors, multiplication is often more complex than a few add and shift operations - small numbers are often very easy to deal with this way, but 575 or 13412 may not be so easy to convert to a small number of simple operations, so a proper multiplication will be needed.

But either way, the computation of the address is the same for both `&array[50]` and `array + 50` - and 99% certain to be calculated by at compile-time. If not known at compile time, the same calculation is performed for `array + x`, `x + array`, `&array[x]` and `&x[array]` - because the `array[x]` and `*(array + x)` (and taking the address operator will just remove the actual access to the element [1](https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/expr.cpp#L358)) are the same thing by the language defintion, and this transformation happens pretty early on in the compilation phase, so they become indistinguishable before the back-end that actually performs the code-generation.

[1](https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/expr.cpp#L358) In my Pascal compiler, I have a function for the Abstract Syntax Tree classes that does `Address`, and the access to a variables value is `value = Load(AST.Address())` or `Store(value, AST.Address())` as a generic solution. See:

[General "Load value".](https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/expr.cpp#L358)

[Calculate address of [multidimensional] array](https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/expr.cpp#L416)

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way? I mean, ´sizeof(foo_t)´ can be determined at compile time, so the calculation of ´sizeof(foo_t) * 50´. Lets say ´sizeof(foo_t) * 50 = x´ so at runtime only an 'add' instruction is necessary to get the position of ´array[50]´ by ´array + x´.

Comment: Actually, the standard clearly says `array[50]` is identical to `*(array + 50)`: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2

Comment: @ViktorLiehr: Assuming the definition of the array is at file-level, a typical compiler will generate both addresses directly, just leaving relocation to the linker/loader.

Comment: Btw: at least on x86 for simple types, the whole thing is a single instruction, even if 50 isn't a compile time constant

Comment: @MikeMB: Unlikely, because it still has to be scaled by `sizeof(struct foo)`. That might only work for some powers of two)

Comment: It is a single instruction if `sizeof(foo_t)` is 1,2,4,8 or 16, it can be made into a single `lea` instruction. If the size is something else, it has to be done at least in two steps, and if the multiplication is complex enough (e.g. 4614), the processor will most likely just do `mul`, then the relevant `add` or `lea`.

Comment: @olaf: yes, sorry I meant types like int double etc. Corrected

Comment: @MikeMB: It's the same on other architectures, e.g. ARM, ColdFire/680x0. Maybe some day, when they really don't know what to do with all the transistors, a full-grown address-ALU will appear. But I'm not very optimistic.

Comment: I updated with a bit more text to explain that it does indeed get resolved to a single constant without any runtime math in the simple case, and a relatively simple operation in the case where the compiler doesn't know the offset.